# IPtables all traffic forwarded to one specific IP

Tags: linux, iptables, forward, traffic

I need to redirect all traffic to one specific ip (in this case a index.html) wIth iptables

let me make it clear:
I've a router with tomcat7 on it, with an logon page. (index.html) with the following url i can get to the log on page(Index.html) ip/URL: 192.168.137.111:8080

wlan ip:(Access point) 192.168.0.1
eth0 ip: 192.168.137.1

i've already checked other questions that has been asked, but i could not fix it. I got the following code i'm trying to use. Im not sure if it works.

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.137.111:8080

what am i doing wrong?

Is it possible to get a rule with iptables that redirects / forwards all traffic to the index.html(192.168.137.111:8080)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your firewall rule says that only TCP traffic to `192.168.0.1:80` is redirected to `192.168.137.111:8080`.

Try:
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.137.111:8080`

I only removed `-d 192.168.0.1` so it catches all TCP connections on port 80.